# XPath: how to select elements that are related to other on the same level

Tags: xpath

The question is simple but I don't have enough practice for this case :)

How to get **price** text value from every div within "block" if we know that we need only **item_promo** elements.

```
<div class="block">
     <div class="item_promo">item</div>
     <div class="item_price">123</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
     <div class="item_promo">item</div>
     <div class="item_price">456</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
     <div class="item_promo">item</div>
     <div class="item_price">789</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
     <div class="item">item</div>
     <div class="item_price">222</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
     <div class="item">item</div>
     <div class="item_price">333</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the xpath :

`//div[@class='block']/*[@class='item_promo']/following-sibling::div[@class='item_price']/text()`

You look for `div` elements that has attribute `class` with value `item_promo` and look at its following sibling which has an attribute `item_price` and grab the text.

Comment: It won't work if change tags order, so I don't recommend to use this approach. Better to use kjhughes's solution from another answer

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
//div[div/@class='item_promo']/div[@class='item_price']
```

will return those `item_price` class `div` elements with sibling `item_promo` class `div` elements:

```
<div class="item_price">123</div>
<div class="item_price">456</div>
<div class="item_price">789</div>
```

This will work regardless of label/price order.