# Trouble scraping data with selenium and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape some data from a web page using selenium. I have successfully got selenium working headlessly on a raspberry pi, I can connect to the webpage I am trying to scrape, return the title of the page and return the URL I am connected to.

I have been looking at examples in tutorials on how to scrape data and they all go something like this:

```
titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(“//a[@class=’text-bold’]”)
```

However, every piece of data in the webpage I am trying to scrape has the same class name. An example of the first bit of data I'm trying to scrape, I'm trying to get the value of wins which is 4:

[Data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nt0W.png)

And a second example of the data im trying to scrape, which in this case is kills and the value is 559:

[Data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNHwo.png)

Both numbers I am trying to scrape share the same class name so I cant simply scrape by class.
What is the best way of scraping this data?

Comment: You'll have to fetch all if the `div.numbers` items.  For each item in that set, fetch the title from the first `<span>` tag to get the type, and the text from the `span.value` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(...)

I think you can do something like this for Data 1 (inside the parentheses)

```
/div/span[@title="Wins"]/following-sibling::span[@class="value"]/text()
```

and similarly for Data 2:

```
/div/span[@title="Kills"]/following-sibling::span[@class="value"]/text()
```

I used the following as references:

[XPath: how to select elements that are related to other on the same level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574159/xpath-how-to-select-elements-that-are-related-to-other-on-the-same-level/45575117)

and tested your code to see the XPath result with this:

[XPath Tester / Evaluator](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output)

Answer (score 0):

You could use css attribute = value selectors to target preceding sibling by title attribute then use adjacent sibling combinator to move to the adjacent sibling and grab the desired values

```
find_element_by_css_selector('[title=Kills] + .value').text
find_element_by_css_selector('[title=Wins] + .value').text
```